# reading and writing .cfg files in python

Tags: python-2.7

I was running my montecarlo simulation in MATLAB using a .cfg file. For now I must rewrite this code in python..as much as I searched I did not find any command that helps me to write and create a .cfg file in python. Is there any body for small sample code of how we can write a .cfg file in python?? Note: I need to stack with config.cfg I cant work with .ini

Comment: You write cfg files the same way you write any other kind of file. Start with `open`...

Comment: Do you want to write a config file using Python? Or read values from one to use in a Python script?

Answer (score 1):

Is the [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) module not suitable for what you want?  I have used it and found it very helpful for file parsing.